# Number of permutations with fixed first and last places

Tags: probability

If I have 3 males and 2 females lining up at a grocery store, how many different ways can they line up if the first person in line is female and the last person in line is male?

Is it as simple as 2x3x2x1x4?

Comment: You should make a genuine attempt to solve the problem and tell us why you're stuck or why you think your answer is wrong. The product you give is not a probability, so it's obviously not the answer. Why do you think it may be a step on the way to an answer? // I won't show the solution for an exact answer, but I will show some clues that may help.

Comment: You should at least be sure that a probability can never be equal to 2x3x2x1x4, 36.  A probability is a number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

**General rule for the probability of an intersection of events.** Maybe consider the following two steps.

(a) $P(\mathrm{First\; in\; line\; is\; woman}) = 2/5$ and
$P(\mathrm{Last\; in\; line\; is\; man}\,|\,\mathrm{First\; in\; line\; is\; woman}) = 3/4.$

(b) Use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A).$

---

**Simulation.** Do a simulation in R.

- The the population ('pop') consists
  of three men (1's) and two women (2's).
- Use the 'sample' function
  to randomly scramble the population.
- Next, check to see if it is
  TRUE that the first in 'line' is a woman and the last is a man.
- Finally, when you finish the loop to look at a million lines,
  the logical vector 'event' has a million TRUEs and FALSEs, and
  the 'mean' of 'event' is the proportion of TRUEs in 'event'.

A million events should be enough to approximate the answer to
two or three decimal places.

```
set.seed(2020)     # for reproducibility
pop = c(1,1,1,2,2)
m = 10^6;  event=logical(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  line = sample(pop)
  event[i] = (line[1]==2 & line[5]==1) 
  }
mean(event)
[1] 0.30028
```

Comment: You may see a question something like this on an upcoming exam, and I hope you learn enough to answer it correctly: Can you answer these? (a) What is the probability women will be first and last in line? (b) What is the probability the first two in line will be men? Different style: (c) If you know ages of the 5 people, what is the probability they will be in line arranged from oldest to youngest? // Do you get (a) 0.1, (b) 0.3, (3) ≈ 0.0083